# How can I add parent fields to a Django InlineFormSet?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How can I add a *parent* field to an [InlineFormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)?

### My attempt:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Child(models.Model):
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py:

```
from .models import Parent, Child
from django import forms

FormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(Parent, Child, 
          fields='__all__'
)
```

views.py:

```
from .models import Parent
from .forms import FormSet

def view(req):
    instance = Parent.objects.get(pk=1)
    form = FormSet(instance=instance)
```

This results in all of the fields from `Child` being displayed, but none from `Parent`.

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this for a while and have found nothing obvious. Adding .select_related() to the queryset has no effect on formsets. Nor does .extra(select=...). The only workaround I have is to individually add fields in the template: `{{form.instance.parent.parent_name}}`.

Comment: @JoeP I did manage to find a solution for my actual models, but it only works for `OneToOne` relationships and not foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround using a `OneToOneField`, however I still don't know how to do this with a `ForeignKey` relationship.

If you have a Parent/Child relationship like this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Child(models.Model):
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True)
```

Adding the key `parent_link=True` to the `OneToOneField` will allow you to reference columns from the parent as if they were the Child's columns.

For example:

```
c = Child.objects.get(id=1)
print(c.parent_name)
```

Also, note that the following is functionally equivalent to the above models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Child(Parent):
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

This concept extends to the fields of any `ModelForm` as well.

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('parent_name', 'child_name')
```

I haven't tested this with `inlineformset_factory`, but since we are treating the `Child` model as an extension of the `Parent` model, there is no need to tell the `formset_factory` about the `Parent` model, thus `modelformset_factory` is all we need:

```
SomeModelFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(Child, form=SomeModelForm)
```

If you are unfamiliar with model inheritance, I would check out the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate Parent Model form, then pass it via context together with your `ChildFormset` :

```
# forms.py

from .models import Parent, Child
from django import forms

ChildFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(Parent, Child, 
          fields='__all__'
)

class ParentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Parent
    fields = ('parent_name',)
```

```
# views.py

from .models import Parent, Child
from .forms import ChildFormSet, ParentForm

def view(request, parent_id):
    parent = Parent.objects.get(pk=parent_id)
    formset = ChildFormSet(queryset=Child.objects.filter(parent=parent))
    form = ParentForm(instance=parent)

    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset
    })
```

```
{# some_template.html #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        Children:
        {{ formset.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```